# What are the T-SQL !< and !> operators for?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Looking at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 I noticed that in addition to the usual comparison operators, T-SQL seems to have `!<` and `!>`. A quick experiment in the interactive console suggests they do what it looks like they should do: not less than, not greater than.

What is the purpose of these operators? At first glance, they would seem to be synonyms of the existing `>=` and `<=` respectively.

One possibility that comes to mind: maybe they are for use with floating-point numbers? IEEE 754 is a context where they are not always synonyms of those existing operators.

Alternatively, maybe they have different semantics in the presence of SQL null values?

Comment: Neither `!<` nor `!>` appear to be part of ANSI SQL.  For that reason alone, it might be considered preferable to not use them, as such code may not port over to SQL databases other than SQL Server.

Comment: They go back to at least SQL Server 2000. I presume added as analogues to `!=` for some reason.. They are documented at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/comparison-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Thanks for the documentation link, @MartinSmith, hope you don't mind I "steal" that for the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> One possibility that comes to mind: maybe they are for use with
> floating-point numbers? IEEE 754 is a context where they are not
> always synonyms of those existing operators.
>
> Alternatively, maybe they have different semantics in the presence of
> SQL null values?

No.

This is just some non standard alternative syntax [also present in Sybase](https://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1570/html/sqlug/sqlug32.htm) so presumably pre-dating the code split (from last century).

If you look at the execution plan you will see that `!<` shows up as `>=` and `!>` as `<=` [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FNJC46cQ). So this non standard syntax doesn't survive as a predicate in the final plan.

The answer to [Authoritative source that <> and != are identical in performance in SQL Server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/155670/3690) also applies.

Note that these operators are similarly paired and have codes `3` and `6` as the return values of `sqllang!DecodeCompOp` in the table shown in that answer so after parsing are treated the same.

```
╔════╦══════╗
║ Op ║ Code ║
╠════╬══════╣
║ <  ║    1 ║
║ =  ║    2 ║
║ <= ║    3 ║
║ !> ║    3 ║
║ >  ║    4 ║
║ <> ║    5 ║
║ != ║    5 ║
║ >= ║    6 ║
║ !< ║    6 ║
╚════╩══════╝
```

Comment: Presence in Sybase explains it's origin.

Answer (score 3):

`!` is effectively adding a logical `NOT` to the operator (in T-SQL), in the same way it does for [`!=`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/not-equal-to-transact-sql-exclamation?view=sql-server-ver16) (not equal to). So [`!>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/not-greater-than-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) would be *not greater than* and [`!<`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/not-less-than-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) would be *not less than*.

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN 1 != 2 THEN 1 END,
       CASE WHEN 1 !< 2 THEN 2 END,
       CASE WHEN 1 !> 2 THEN 3 END,
       CASE WHEN 2 != 1 THEN 4 END,
       CASE WHEN 2 !< 1 THEN 5 END,
       CASE WHEN 2 !> 1 THEN 6 END;
```

From an ANSI perspective, `!=` would be [`<>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/not-equal-to-transact-sql-traditional?view=sql-server-ver16), while `!>`/`!<` would be `NOT <Expression> >|< <Expression>` ([`NOT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/not-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), [`>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/greater-than-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), [`<`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/less-than-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)).

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN 1 <> 2 THEN 1 END,
       CASE WHEN NOT 1 < 2 THEN 2 END,
       CASE WHEN NOT 1 > 2 THEN 3 END,
       CASE WHEN 2 <> 1 THEN 4 END,
       CASE WHEN NOT 2 < 1 THEN 5 END,
       CASE WHEN NOT 2 > 1 THEN 6 END;
```

Like the rest of the operators, they act the same with `NULL` values; `NULL !> 1` would resolve the UNKNOWN.

Confusingly(?) there is no `!>=`/`!<=` operator, attempting this will generate an error:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN 2 !<= 1 THEN 7 END;

SELECT CASE WHEN 2 !>= 1 THEN 8 END;
```

> Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: I had never seen this operator! thumbs up!

Comment: Honestly, neither had I until today, @Alex .

Comment: If they added `!<=` and `!<=` operators, I'm sure someone would have also made a case to also add the `!<>` operator. Next someone would suggest `=<`, `=>`, `><`, `!=<`,  `!=>`, and  `!><`.

Comment: I *hate* that you're probably right, @TN ...

Answer (score 1):

These are actually [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/comparison-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16):

| Operator | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| !< (Not Less Than) | Not less than (not ISO standard) |
| !> (Not Greater Than) | Not greater than (not ISO standard) |

I would rather use >= and <= operators respectively.